# Notice: Undefined variable en variable no vacias

Tags: php

Me muestra el siguiente error:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: data_setup
Notice: Undefined variable: poster
```

En dichas variables que no estan vacias, identificando el error en el siguiente código:

```
$poster .= 'poster="assets/img/website/upload/image/'.$image.'"';
$data_setup .= "data-setup='{&quot;controls&quot;:true,&quot;autoplay&quot;:false,&quot;preload&quot;:&quot;auto&quot;,&quot;aspectRatio&quot;:&quot;640:267&quot;,&quot;playbackRates&quot;:[1,1.5,2]}'";
```

No recuerdo como se llama el uso de esto `.=` podrían indicar su nombre.

No entiendo porque me genera ese error, podrían explicarme por favor.

---

```
        $stmt->bind_result($preview_video, $image, $multimedia);
        while ($stmt->fetch()) {

            if(!is_null($image)){
                $poster .= 'poster="assets/img/'.$image.'"';
            }

            $data_setup .= "data-setup='{&quot;controls&quot;:true,&quot;autoplay&quot;:false,&quot;preload&quot;:&quot;auto&quot;,&quot;aspectRatio&quot;:&quot;640:267&quot;,&quot;playbackRates&quot;:[1,1.5,2]}'";

            if($preview_video === 'yes') {
                echo '<video width="100%" height="100%" controls '.$poster.'  oncontextmenu="return false" controlsList="nodownload" '.$data_setup.'>
                <source src="'.$multimedia.'" type="video/mp4">
                </video>';
            }
        }
```

Comment: Hacer esto `.=$variable` indica que la misma fue declarada e inicializada con un valor previamente, ¿nos muestras donde existen previamente dichas variables?

Comment: @Aprendiz Hola, he editado la pregunta

Comment: las 2 variables que están fuera del while son las que declaras cierto?

Comment: @Aprendiz Ese es mi código amigo, no existe más, el error que me muestra identifica aquellas variables que están dentro del `while`

Comment: `$poster .= "algo";` es igual a `$poster = $poster . "algo";` si `$poster` no existe previo al `.=` da el notice `variable no definida: poster`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cuando haces esto:

```
$var1 .= 1;
$var2 .= 2;
```

Estás indicando lo siguiente:

> Una variable de nombre var1 y una variable de nombre var2 fueron declaradas con anterioridad y ahora les estoy concatenando, un valor anexo al que ya tenían declarado.

Como tu hiciste eso, para el intérprete de PHP es imposible encontrar la declaración inicial de dichas variables, pues no existen y por tanto me da un error como el siguiente:

> NOTICE Undefined variable: data on line number 3
>
> NOTICE Undefined variable: data2 on line number 5

Caso contrario si yo ahora dejo mi script del modo siguiente:

```
<?php

$data = 0;
$data2 = 10;

$data .= 1;

$data2 .= 2;

echo $data;
```

Va a funcionar y me imprimirá:

> 01

¿Por qué?

Bueno el intérprete de PHP encuentra la declaración inicial de la variable `$var1` y `$var2` y posterior lee que existe la necesidad de a cada una concatenarle un valor extra haciendo uso de: `.=`

Por lo tanto en tu código lo que deberías hacer es: **quitar dicha sintaxis y solo dejar el símbolo de =** así:

```
$stmt->bind_result($preview_video, $image, $multimedia);
while ($stmt->fetch()) {

    if(!is_null($image)){
        $poster = 'poster="assets/img/'.$image.'"';
    }

    $data_setup = "data-setup='{&quot;controls&quot;:true,&quot;autoplay&quot;:false,&quot;preload&quot;:&quot;auto&quot;,&quot;aspectRatio&quot;:&quot;640:267&quot;,&quot;playbackRates&quot;:[1,1.5,2]}'";

    if($preview_video === 'yes') {
        echo '<video width="100%" height="100%" controls '.$poster.'  oncontextmenu="return false" controlsList="nodownload" '.$data_setup.'>
        <source src="'.$multimedia.'" type="video/mp4">
        </video>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Gracias por su respuesta.

Comment: Cuidado! Si **$image** es null, no se asignará la variable **$poster** por lo que te saltará un warning en _echo '<video width="100%" height="100%" controls '.$poster.'_

Answer (score 2):

.= se usa para la unión, el error te lo muestra por que te está indicando que no ha sido declarado anteriormente.

Debido a que es una consulta a la base de datos dentro del while, puedes solucionarlo así:

```
        $stmt->bind_result($preview_video, $image, $multimedia);
        while ($stmt->fetch()) {

            $poster = ''; // Crea la variable y evita que te de error si no está cuando la llamas
            if(!is_null($image)){
                $poster .= 'poster="assets/img/'.$image.'"';
            }

            $data_setup = "data-setup='{&quot;controls&quot;:true,&quot;autoplay&quot;:false,&quot;preload&quot;:&quot;auto&quot;,&quot;aspectRatio&quot;:&quot;640:267&quot;,&quot;playbackRates&quot;:[1,1.5,2]}'";

            if($preview_video === 'yes') {
                echo '<video width="100%" height="100%" controls '.$poster.'  oncontextmenu="return false" controlsList="nodownload" '.$data_setup.'>
                <source src="'.$multimedia.'" type="video/mp4">
                </video>';
            }
        }
```

Comment: Gracias por su respuesta.